# Error after create constructor in inherited class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

i am having problem when i make constructor in the Rechteck class the Error is see line in code commented* (no matching function for call to 'Form::Form()'|) the Form class works great .i am using Code::Blocks.Thanks

```
  class Form
{
protected:
    std::string     name;    
    sf::Vector2f    bezugsp; 
    sf::Color       farbe;   
    sf::VertexArray punkte;  
public:

    Form(const std::string &n, const sf::Vector2f &bp=sf::Vector2f(0.,0.),
         const sf::Color fa=sf::Color::Black){}
    ~Form();                    

    std::string get_name() const{}       
    sf::VertexArray get_punkte() const{} 
    sf::Vector2f get_bezugsp() const{}   
    void set_bezugsp(const sf::Vector2f bp){} 
    void set_farbe(const sf::Color fa){}

    void gen_array(){}           
 };


class Rechteck : public Form
{
public:

    float hoehe=0;
    float breite=0;

    Rechteck(){    //AT THIS LINE ERROR************

    }

    virtual ~Rechteck(){}

    void dew(){}

protected:

private:
};
```

Comment: The constructor of `Rechteck` tries to invoke the default constructor of `Form` which doesn't exist. You can reinstate that constructor with `Form() = default;`.

Comment: All or none. https://arne-mertz.de/2015/02/the-rule-of-zero-revisited-the-rule-of-all-or-nothing

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am not allowed to modify Form class.The Problem should be solved without modifying Form class

Comment: Then call the appropriate constructor of  `Form` in the member initializer list of `Rechteck`.

Comment: [Documentation just in case no one has covered the Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) in any of your C++ reference materials (an unfortunately common circumstance).